# Using value from a JTextBox in SELECT query in mysql

Tags: java

I have a textbox. When the user enters the name in the textbox I want the details fetched from  the table

```
String getTxt = text.getText();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors_4 WHERE self_authors="+getTxt);
```

On executing this i'm getting exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
```

What is the solution to this. Need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing single quotes:

```
st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors_4 WHERE self_authors='" + getTxt + "'");
```

Better use a `PreparedStatement` to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You are using ' "+getTxt+" ' ` ", shouldnt it be ' "+getTxt+" ' "